# How can I upload youtube video in python or any other language without using YouTube data api?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I written a code(In python) to automatically upload videos to YouTube
Now, the problem:
I can only upload 6 videos (quota limit = 10,000/day)

Is there any way to upload video on YouTube by python or any other language

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to upload videos to YouTube.  You can do it manually though the YouTube web application or you can do it programmatically though the [YouTube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

The [YouTube data api has a cost based quota system](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost). Which means that you are given a default of 10000 quota points, and each request you make costs something against that quota. [Inserting videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) for example costs 1600 quota points.

> Is there any way to upload video on YouTube by python or any other language

The programming language you use does not matter, the quota will be the same. So no there is no other way of uploading videos to YouTube using the api.

You should just request a [quota extension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits) if you need to upload more videos.