# Upload Youtube Videos from Browser Console

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, browser-console, video-upload

Youtube videos can be uploaded by console with `youtube data api v3`. (they only let you upload 6 videos per day).

Manually 15 videos at a time can be uploaded on youtube through [web application](https://studio.youtube.com).

Is there any `javascript code` that will let me upload video from a folder and it will upload automatically all videos in my that folder. I will run that code on Browser's console tab or operating system (Node.js).

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846569/14153679), you could try to request a quota extension.

Searched on npm and found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-videos-uploader-oni) among others.

Comment: Thanks Kevin & Benjamin. NPM package seems more easier.